# No copy when calling SetByteArrayRegion when the starting address is not zero

Tags: java, java-native-interface

I am trying to copy of a (very large) byte array from a C program to my main Java program in using JNI.

I am  using the following code:

```
JNIEXPORT void JNICALL Java_connectors_javaConnector_updateMap
(JNIEnv *env, jobject jo, jbyteArray byteArray)
{
nextmapping_map[11]=111;
int from = 0;
int size = 20;
  (*env)->SetByteArrayRegion(env, byteArray, from, size,nextmapping_map);
    printf("Copied chunk: %d -> %d\n", from, to);
}
```

My point is that the code works correctly only when `from == 0` : if I go in my main program and I request the value of `nextmapping_map`, I get 111 as expected.
However, if `from > 0` (which is necessary because my array is too large to be copied in one time) then I get a wrong value for `nextmapping_map`.

This behaviour is quite weird. Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Which value are you using for `from`, which index of nextmapping_map do you set and which index of the bytearray are you trying to read from? The offset is only into the bytearray, not the native buffer. Is that the misunderstanding? You may need to pass `nextmapping_map + from` as the last parameter, but it's not clear what behaviour you are expecting.

Comment: Define 'array is too large to be copied in one time'. Why? No limit is stated in the [JNI Specification](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/jni/spec/functions.html#Set_PrimitiveType_ArrayRegion_routines).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `from` parameter passed to `SetByteArrayRegion` is the index to the java array. It is not an index to C array.

For example let have C array `a`:

```
{ 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9 }
```

and java `byteArray` initialized to all 42:

```
{ 42, 42, 42, 42, 42, 42, 42, 42, 42, 42, 42, 42, ...
```

then `SetByteArrayRegion(env, byteArray, 3, 4, a)` copies 4 elements from array `a` starting at index `0` to `byteArray` position index `3`. The result in `byteArray` will be:

```
{ 42, 42, 42, 0, 1, 2, 3, 42, 42, 42, 42, 42, ...
```

When it needed to copy a region from a C array to a java array and keep indexes then it is necessary to add offset to the beginning of the C array:

```
SetByteArrayRegion(env, byteArray, from, size, a + from);
```